# Function space of a finite set and $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I read in a tutorial that a function space $F(S, \mathbb{R})$ of a finite set $S$ of cardinality $n$ has dimension $n$. To be clear $F(S, \mathbb{R})$ is the set of all functions defined on the set $S$.

i.e. $\dim(F(S, \mathbb{R})) = n = |S|$.

Further the tutorial went on to assert elsewhere, that $F(S, \mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}^n$.

I understand how the former follows trivially from the latter, but I am not sure how/why the latter is true. Can you provide a proof/ some intuition as to why this is true ?
(A link to any resource would do).

ps. I have a fairly good applied math/ engineering background and a decent working knowledge of linear algebra. But this is the first time I am learning Functional Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Let us write the set $S$ as $S = \{1,2, \dots, n\}$. Given a vector $(a_1, \cdots, a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we can associate to it the function $f(n) = a_n$. Conversely, given a function $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$, we can associate to it the vector $(f(1), \cdots, f(n)) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Check that this correspondence is compatible with the scaling and addition structures on both $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F(S,\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}$. Define

$$\varphi:F(S,\Bbb R)\to\Bbb R^n:f\mapsto\big\langle f(s_1),f(s_2),\dots,f(s_n)\big\rangle\;;$$

it’s very straightforward now to show that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Basically $S$ just provides a way to keep a list of $n$ real numbers straight: we can do it by ‘tagging’ each of the real numbers with a specific $s_k\in S$, or we can do it implicitly by writing the $n$ real numbers as an $n$-tuple, with a built-in ordering.